# bash command with variable

Tags: git, bash, shell, amazon-s3

This is a crazy newbie question I'm sure. I need to execute this command:

```
aws s3 sync dist s3://bucket/path --acl public-read --delete --region us-east-1
```

I'd like to make the `s3://bucket/path` portion dynamic. I have an environment variable to know what git branch I'm on and I'd like the URL to be dependant on that git branch.

So, for the purpose of this example, let's assume I had three branches that each map to their own s3 bucket:

- master => s3://master_url.com
- staging => s3://staging_url.com
- production => s3://production_url.com

Let's say that the branch name is in the environment variable called `GIT_BRANCH`. How could I write my script so it determines which URL to use and executes the script with that URL?

Comment: If there isn't a simple mapping of url component to variable value then you'll need to use an `if` or `case` statement to switch urls based on variable value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an [if-else](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-if-statement-examples/) statement that compares your [variable](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html) to the [string](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) if you want.

In case you're unsure, you can read your variable names in from the command prompt. So you're program could be

```
./myProgram.sh master
```

and you would read in master as your string you want to check.

This is essentially a switch statement in bash. There may be a way to explicitly use switch statements in bash, but this will work and is fine practice.

Comment: I figured that, I think my question is more what does the actual command look like (with the temporary variable)? Something like: `aws s3 sync dist $S3_BUCKET --acl public-read --delete --region us-east-1` ?

Comment: Yes, that would do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way is to use a variable inside the string:
`aws s3 sync dist s3://${GIT_BRANCH}/path --acl public-read --delete --region us-east-1`

And ${GIT_BRANCH} could be:

- master_url.com
- staing_url.com
- production_url.com

Even more, you could put the path inside GIT_BRANCH, but I do know your configuration